# How to show data using ajax

Tags: php

how can i display the output from ajax and avoid to display the data using php echo inorder to prevent duplicate the same result when page refreshed or when reply or delete link clicked?

here are my codes

**table_comments.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`idparent` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT "0",
`user` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci  NOT NULL,
`text` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=MyISAM 
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

**action.php**

```
<?php
include ("db_connect.php");

// Get the variables from forms 
$user = $_REQUEST['user'];
$text = $_REQUEST['text'];
$comment_on = $_REQUEST['comment_on'];
$ParentId = $_REQUEST['ParentId'];
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];

if ($action == "add") {
  // Add data to the database       
  $query = "INSERT into `comments` VALUES (NULL,'{$ParentId}','{$user}','{$text}',NOW(),'{$comment_on}')";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
}

if ($action == "delete") {
  // Delete data from the database      
  $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `comments` WHERE id=$text");
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8') ?>
<html>
  <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="table_content" >//Display result using ajax</div>

    <script>    
      function show_messages()
      {
        $.ajax({
          url: "index.php",
          cache: false,
          success: function(html){
            $("#table_content").html(html);
          }
        });
      } 

      function clean_form() 
      {
        $("#user").val('name');
        $("#text").val('comment');
      }

      $(document).ready(function(){
        // show_messages();

      });
    </script> 

    <script>
    function DeleteComment(number) // Function to remove comments with id = number
    {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "action.php",                  
        data: "user=1"+"&text="+number+"&ParentId=1"+"&action=delete",                  
        success: function(html){                        
          // show_messages();               
           }
      });
    }

    function AnswerComment (id) // Send the comment numbers , which correspond to
    {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",                   
        data: "AnswerId="+id,                   
        success: function(html){                        
          $("#table_content").html(html);               
           }
      });       
    }

    function SendComment () // Send data from the form
    {
      var user1 = $("#user").val();
      var text1  = $("#text").val();    
      var ParentId1  = $("#ParentId").val() + "";   
      if (user1 =='' || user1 =='name')
      {
        alert ("Enter your Username");
        return false;
      }
      if (text1 =='' || text1 =='comment')
      {
        alert ("Enter name to comment");
        return false;
      } 

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "action.php",                  
        data: "user="+user1+"&text="+text1+"&ParentId="+ParentId1+"&action=add",        
        success: function(html){                
            // show_messages();
          // clean_form();      
             }
        });
        return false;
      }
    </script>

    <?php
    function ShowForm($AnswerCommentId) // Form add a comment
    {
      ?> <br/>  
      <form id="myForm" action="">  
      <input id="user" name="user" value="name" autocomplete="off" 
        onfocus="if(this.value == 'name'){this.value = ''}" 
        onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value = 'name'}"/>                
      <br/><br/>
      <textarea id='text' name='text' value="comment" 
          onfocus="if(this.value == 'comment'){this.value = ''}" 
          onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value = 'comment'}" ></Textarea>        
      <input id="ParentId" name="ParentId" type="hidden" value="<?php echo($AnswerCommentId);?>"/>
      <br/>
      <button type='button' OnClick=SendComment()>Comment</button>
      </form>
      <br/>
      <?php
    }

    include ("db_connect.php"); // Connect to the database

    $query="SELECT * FROM `comments` ORDER BY id ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    // Read the comment number to which the answer , if it exists
    if (isset($_REQUEST['AnswerId']))
    {
      $AnswerId = $_REQUEST['AnswerId'];    
    }
    else
    {
      $AnswerId = 0; 
    }

    // Read comments from the database and writing the array                
    $i=0;
    while ($mytablerow = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
      $mytable[$i] = $mytablerow;   
      $i++; 
    }

    // Function for constructing a tree Comments
    function tree($treeArray, $level, $pid = 0) {
      global $AnswerId;
      if (!$treeArray) {
        return;
      }
      foreach ($treeArray as $item) {
        if ($item[1] == $pid) {
          ?>    
                <!-- Showing each comment with the correct indentation -->
                <div class="CommentWithReplyDiv" style="margin-left:<?php echo($level * 60); ?>px">     
                <div class="CommentDiv">
                <pre class="Message"><?php echo($item[3]); ?></pre>
                <div class="User"><?php echo($item[2]); ?></div>
                <div class="Date"><?php echo($item[4]); ?></div>
          <?php
          if ($level <= 4) {  // Limit nesting level
            echo '<a href="" class="ReplyLink" onclick="AnswerComment(' . $item[0] . ');return false;">Reply</a>';
          }
          echo '<a href="" class="DeleteLink" onclick="DeleteComment(' . $item[0] . ');return false;">Delete</a>';
          ?> </div> <?php
          // Display the form for an answer, if the answer Comment
          if ($AnswerId == $item[0]) {
            ?><div id="InnerDiv"><?php
            ShowForm($AnswerId);
            ?></div><?php
          }
          ?> </div> <?php
          echo ('<br/>');
          tree($treeArray, $level + 1, $item[0]); // Recursion
        }
      }
    }

    tree($mytable, 0);
    ?>

    <!-- Reply form at the bottom of the page-->
    <br/>
    <a href="" id="LeaveCommentLink">leave a comment</a>
    <div id="MainAnswerForm" style="display:none;">
      <?php
      ShowForm(0);
      ?>
    </div>
    <div id="AfterMainAnswerForm"></div>

    <script>
    // The emergence reply form at the bottom of the page when you click on the link
    $(document).ready(function(){   
      $("#LeaveCommentLink").click(function () {
        $("#InnerDiv").remove();
        $("#MainAnswerForm").slideToggle("normal");
        return false;
      });
    });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, separate database access, business logic and view layer, as well as JavaScript code and HTML markup.
You are including the whole `index.php` output again in your `show_messages()` method, including JavaScript and the `<body>` (which is probably the cause of duplicate entries)! Write a seperate file that just returns the comments in HTML and use that in your AJAX call.

Comment: Thank you for your advice,  It works fine if I created another file to show the comments. But, my problem is when I'm trying to create one php file that will include ajax and php codes so, it can simplfy my work when I want to include  comment.php file in different pages so, it can display comments of the page. How can I do that?

Comment: Just like you did with `db_connect.php`: Refactor redundant code into its own file and `include` or even `require` it (require will fail if the file is missing whereas include will only warn). The code will be executed as if it were copy-pasted at that exact point. You might also want to look into frameworks such as Symfony or Zend because doing everything from scratch is out of style since 1999.

Comment: Hello, I'm back again. I want to display "index.php" using JSON encode, how can I do to show the data with JSON variable anD aJax?